# Unity - Object being destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

Let the following :

- `A` : has several `B` children ;
- `B` : is the child of an `A`.
- The whole parent => children tree must be destroyed whenever any part of the tree is destroyed. I.e delete a `B` and it must also delete its parent `A` and its **B** siblings. Delete the parent `A` and it must also delete its `B` children ;

The problem is : how do I prevent recursion here ?

For example, if a `B` gets deleted, upon destruction, it will attempt to destroy its parent `A` (or its `B` siblings) which, in turn, will also attempt to destroy the `B` that is already *being* destroyed.

Unity has a weird overload of the `== operator` which allows to check whether an object *has been* destroyed, but doesn't allow to know whether it is *being* destroyed.

Thus, I thought about creating some sort of "extended" `MonoBehaviour` class that I would use as a base for all my objects in the place of a `MonoBehaviour`.

This call would allow me to have extra things that I would have liked to have in a standard `MonoBehaviour`, like :

- On destroying event ;
- On destroyed event ;
- Is being destroyed. This would fix my recursion issue ;
- Is destroyed ;
- Other features that would be all-purpose enough to be present in any component, such as the ones above.

The problem with this solution is the weird way Unity calls its "event methods" (`Awake()`, etc). It seems like Unity only cares about the event methods defined in leaf classes. Thus, this solution would require all my sub classes to explicitly define some event methods (`Awake()`, `OnDestroy()`) for the sole purpose of calling the same methods from the base class (i.e "extended" `MonoBehaviour`).

This seems dirty, because it's obviously not the way Unity wants people to use their engine, and also because there are high chances that, in some components where I would not need those event methods, I would forget to still declare them in order to call the ones from the base class.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I missed something obvious. Destroying an object destroys all of its transform children automatically. What's not clear is *when* an object is actually destroyed. It might not happen until end of frame or the start of the next frame. Hmmm.

Comment: Actually, from the Unity docs: "Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but is always done before rendering.". So, `B` can just go ahead and destroy A. After all the `Update`s are done, `A` and all of its children will be destroyed by the engine without recursion, or running code from a destroyed object. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Comment: What is the scenario where one of your child classes is being destroyed, what is destroying them?

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. Unity will not call OnDestroy again if it has already been called once, is that so ? But this doesn't solve the issue if I want to destroy my objects synchronously (i.e using DestroyImmediate()).

Comment: It's not clear to me what your pb, is it Unity lifecycle methods or are you asking how to remove all items of a tree whether a A or a B is hit?

Comment: @Everts Well, actually, it's both. I do have a solution to solve this recursion issue, but that solution comes in conflict with the way Unity works, i.e it only cares about "event methods" being defined in leaf classes rather than making use of virtual.